# TCP/IP Connection between multiple nodes for a distributed framework

Tags: c++11, tcp, distributed-system

I am trying to achieve TCP/IP connections between multiple nodes. I understand how TCP connections work but I cannot have a server-client based approach here since every node must connect with every other node. How should I achieve this?

(I cannot use Nanomessage or ZeroMQ libraries)

Please help. Noob here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the demand that every node must connect with eacy other node doesn't mean we can't use C/S module.

You can build a central controller as a server, every node connects to the server to get the nodes table of all the other nodes, and then connects to them.

Actually, it is a prototype of ICE structure which is used for NAT traversal. And I think you may use it directly without write one for yourself, because if your nodes are not all in WLAN, you may also have to face the problem of NAT traversal.